# Having a struct variable represent the label

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm really new to c and was using a struct to return an array, I managed to generate the struct just fine and use the struct as well, but I made a really ugly way of importing my array into my struct. Is there some way that I can do this with a for loop?

Here's my code that I currently use to transfer the array into the struct:

```
result.a = input3[0];
result.b = input3[1];
result.c = input3[2];
result.d = input3[3];
result.e = input3[4];
result.f = input3[5];
result.g = input3[6];
result.h = input3[7];
result.i = input3[8];
```

I tried to have it work like this:

```
for (char j = 'a'; j <= 'i'; j++)
{
    result.j = input[j - 97];
}
```

But, as makes sense, the error I get is 'j': is not a member of values and it refuses to compile. What formatting would it take to make the program realize that I'm trying to refrence a variable, and not the index of the struct?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: That's not how `C` works. `Lua` works that way. `Perl` does something alike. But `C` is very, very different.

Comment: Provide that part of code where,  you defined your struct. Moreover, assuming that `'a'` will have its code `97` every machine is incorrect, instead use expressions like this, `j-'a'`.

Comment: That's an XY problem. Use an array in the `struct`.

Comment: Arrays and structs are two different things for two different purposes. If your problem is best solved by an array, use an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In C, the names of members of structs are known to the compiler; they are used only while compiling. They are not part of the running program (except for debugging features and possible compiler-specific extensions to the language).

A primary purpose of arrays is to work with multiple elements in a programmatic way (that is, in a way that is computed when the program is running). Subscripts are for selecting members.

If you want to have multiple items in a struct that you can address programmatically, then you can define your struct to have an array in it, such as:

```
struct Foo;
{
    int MyArray[10];
}
…
struct Foo MyFoo;
```

Then you can refer to items in the array inside `MyFoo` with `MyFoo.MyArray[i]`. You will have to use numbers for subscripts.

Comment: If the only element of the struct is an array, you should just use a bare array instead. (I'm sure you know this, but hope the OP will read my comment. Or you can edit your answer to include this caveat.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: They could use a bare array, but they said they were using it to return an array, and you cannot return an array from a function. We could discuss various ways to return array contents from a function, like having the caller pass the address or doing dynamic memory allocation, but that’s a can of worms for a new learner.

Comment: Ahhh...I missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

`struct` and `array` are two different animals and you should use the one which is most appropriate for the job. An `array` is meant to store a list of elements all of the same type. The elements of an array are accessed by a numeric index, so there is an ordering to the elements. On the other hand, a `struct` is intended to hold related data which may be of different types. You access the members of a struct by name. This allows us to ignore the order of the elements.

Granted, you can have an array inside a `struct`, but unless there are other data elements in the `struct` as well, you should just use a bare array instead of a `struct` with an array member.